# Exposing apache webserver to internet for SVN repository access

Tags: router, apache-http-server, svn

At the moment I have an Apache server on the local network.  That is, it is accessible via local network. For example,

```
http://192.168.1.1/svn/repos/blahblah
```

is accessible from my computer. However, I would like to be able to access the repository from any connection.  What is odd is that the host computer has Windows Firewall off, and is in the router's DMZ.

What am I missing here?

Comment: your isp may be blocking incoming connections. what happens if you run [ShieldsUp!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) from this computer?

Comment: hmm... every single port it came up with was closed. this is interesting, as i spent about 1.5 hours yesterday trying to open port 3389 for Remote Desktop on another computer. i tried various google solutions, but the port simply wouldn't open, even though 'everything' obvious said it was. hmmm...

Comment: what happens if you run the test with a computer plugged straight into the modem (no router in between)?